# How to aggregate array of document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following schema:

```
var orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    deleted: Boolean,
    clientName: String,
    clientPhone: String,
    products: [{
        name: String,
        quantity: Number,
        price: Number
    }],
    observations: String,
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    seller: String,
    orderNumber: Number,
    total: Number
});
```

And I want to make an aggregate query that sums each product and add `quantity*price` to the `total`, and return me the total. However, I only know how to do it if I had multiple products, each one as a document, and then sum over all the documents but not this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) :

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $addFields: {
        "total": {
            $reduce: {
                input: "$products",
                initialValue: '$total',
                in: { $add: [{ $multiply: ["$$this.quantity", "$$this.price"] }, '$$value'] }
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AZPfd0SUfvu)

Comment: what is total??

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs : I didn't get that ? `total = total + sum of quantity*price of all products`..

Comment: You add a field "total" into the document. What if I want to return a new document only with the total field? instead of addFields I return a new document

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs : You can try with `$project` instead `$addFields`, also add `_id:0` in project to exclude that as well.. Generally `$addFields` would replace exiting `Total` field with new value or if it not there it will a new field to column..